# Multiple Documents with shared TOC and Indexes

Tags: cross-referencing, context

I've recently started a personal project for creating and managing a knowledge base, but with the individual pages written in ConTeXt instead of markup, markdown, or any of the other currently-popular choices.

I'm very new to ConTeXt and have not seen any examples doing what I'm trying to do.  It may simply be that I do not know the right place to look.

I'd like to be able to cross-link between pages and produce metadata pages covering the entire contents (e.g. TOC, index, list of figures).

At the moment I am not concerned with rendering these pages as HTML (but may be at some point).  Ideally the output will be a set of cross-linked PDFs: one for each topic plus separate PDFs for the TOC, index, and any lists of figures/tables/whatever that I decide to produce.

Any pointers?

Comment: **Welcome to TeX.se! I hope you'll have a good time here.** About your question: the current title led me up a garden path, it made me think you wanted a hybrid TOC/index. Perhaps "Multiple documents with a shared TOC and indexes" would be a better title? That would make the question easier to spot for future help-seekers. You can edit the question, including its tags and title, via the ‘edit’ link at its foot.

Comment: Esteis, that's an excellent suggestion.  Thanks.  :)

Comment: For cross link between documents, see http://pragma-ade.com/show-mag-15.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a combined TOC of two files `a.tex` and `b.tex`, first compile both of them individually, and then create a third file as follows:

```
\starttext
\ctxlua{job.load("a.tuc")}
\placecontent
\ctxlua{job.load("b.tuc")}
\placecontent

\stoptext
```

This, however, does not create proper hyperlinks.

Comment: This looks like it requires the use of LuaTeX.  If that is the case, is there a XeTeX equivalent?  If the links were important to me, would it be safe to say that it's not generally possible?

Comment: Yes, this solution is for MkIV. Is there a specific reason that you are using MkII+xetex? For the last three years all of the ConTeXt development has been focused on MkIV. Regarding the links, all the information is in the `.tuc` file. So, getting the right links is doable. One needs to read the `.tuc` file (essentially a large lua table), and generate appropriate links. I am not familiar with the internals, so it may be better to post on the context mailing list.

Comment: As I said before, I'm very new to ConTeXt so I wasn't aware that there XeTeX had been left behind completely.  I started off with XeTeX because I'd read that it had better Unicode support than LuaTeX and I didn't expect that I would need Lua.

Comment: For Latin and CJK languages, LuaTeX (or at least ConTeXt) offers the same support as XeTeX. ConTeXt+LuaTeX currently does not support Indic languages, so if you need those, you are better off with ConTeXt+XeTeX. ConTeXt development has moved to LuaTeX because Lua is an easier language to program than TeX. ConTeXt+XeTeX still works well, but if you need new features (like the one you described), you are on your own. With ConTeXt+LuaTeX, if you post your question to the ConTeXt Mailing list, you will get a few solutions.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, not simply because it's the only answer but even though it's a half answer it (and the comments on it) do tell the whole story - Lua is the answer.