# Can TeXstudio automatically produce a combined list of todo notes from different documents?

Tags: texstudio, todonotes

I am keeping notes for several (5) projects in Latex.

- Each project gets its own folder with a set of Latex source files (mostly one main file that `input`s the individual chapters).
- Each project is compiled into one PDF file.
- I usually work on one project at a time.
- All projects `input` a single `Preamble.tex` in a separate, 6th folder.
- All projects use `hyperref` and `biblatex` (in case these are relevant).
- All projects are `\documentclass{report}`, though hopefully this won't matter.

I am using `todonotes` to make todo notes for myself which show parts of each document that needs work. This package makes an index of all notes with `\listoftodos`, which is already very useful. But when each project has its own list of todos, and if I want to ask "which project's todos should I work on today?", I have to open all 5 PDFs and keep alt-tabbing back and forth between them.

I would like one of the following to happen:

- Every time I compile any of the PDFs in TeXstudio, a 6th PDF is automatically generated which has a list of todos from every project.
- Whenever I want an up-to-date combined list of todos, I compile a separate document made for this purpose (or run a single non-interactive script) which generates a list of todos. I know that it isn't too difficult to write a C# (or other language) program to grab the relevant pages from each PDF, but perhaps there is a more elegant way.

The combined list of todos should group todos from each project in their own section. I don't care if it doesn't have links (I just want to get, at a glance and in a single step, an idea of what project needs what work done), though the solution shouldn't break the hyperlinked list of todos I already get in each individual document.

There are two related questions I found:

- [Multiple Documents with shared TOC and Indexes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94253/multiple-documents-with-shared-toc-and-indexes) seems related but I am using TeXstudio and MiKTeX, not ConTeXt. I found a `.toc` file which looks like a list of sections (probably used to make the TOC), but I don't know what file has an index of the todos.
- [How to produce a combined index from multiple documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/how-to-produce-a-combined-index-from-multiple-documents) is a similar problem, but I don't understand the solution at all and so cannot adapt it to my todo notes.

Comment: Hi! Could you please make two small example documents with some todo notes, that we could fiddle with?